# Formatting python calculation variables to print, using one string

Tags: python, string-formatting

```
SharesPurchased = 2000
PricePaid = 40
Commission = .03
SellPrice = 42.75

TotalPricePaid = SharesPurchased * PricePaid
CommissionPaid = TotalPricePaid * Commission
TotalSellPrice = SellPrice * SharesPurchased
CommissionSellPaid = TotalSellPrice * Commission
ProfitIfAny = TotalSellPrice - TotalPricePaid - CommissionPaid - 
CommissionSellPaid

print ("""
Joe paid {} for his shares.
Joe paid () to his broker for purchases.
Joe sold his shares for {}
Joe paid {} to his broker for selling his shares.
Joe made a total of {}
"""
       ).format([TotalPricePaid, CommissionPaid, TotalSellPrice, CommissionSellPaid, ProfitIfAny])
```

Here's my spaghetti of code. I'm trying to figure this out for my first actual assignment in python. I can't seem to figure out how to get the assigned variables to pop into text without having to make 5 seperate print("").f lines in a row.

This is what I've produced for a working version :

```
print("Joe paid {} for his shares.").format(TotalPricePaid)
print("Joe paid {} to his broker for purchases.").format(CommissionPaid)
print("Joe sold his shares for {}").format(TotalSellPrice)
print("Joe paid {} to his broker for selling his 
shares.").format(CommissionSellPaid)
print("Joe made a total of {}.").format(ProfitIfAny)
```

Comment: Note that the code you posted won't throw the exception you used in your title. That throws `AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'format'` instead. I've updated the title.

Answer (score 3):

You are passing in one argument to `str.format()`, a list:

```
....format([TotalPricePaid, CommissionPaid, TotalSellPrice, CommissionSellPaid, ProfitIfAny])
```

You need to pass in *separate arguments* instead. Remove the `[...]` list brackets.

You are also using `()` in one location where you probably wanted `CommisionPaid` to be interpolated:

```
Joe paid () to his broker for purchases.
```

Replace those `()` with `{}`

Next, you are applying the `.format()` method to whatever `print()` returns, which is always `None`. Use the `.format()` call on the *string*, not the `print()` call, and pass the *result* to `print()`:

```
print ("""
...""".format(...))
```

The following works:

```
print ("""
Joe paid {} for his shares.
Joe paid {} to his broker for purchases.
Joe sold his shares for {}
Joe paid {} to his broker for selling his shares.
Joe made a total of {}
""".format(TotalPricePaid, CommissionPaid, TotalSellPrice, CommissionSellPaid, ProfitIfAny))
```

or, slightly better formatted:

```
print("""\
Joe paid {} for his shares.
Joe paid {} to his broker for purchases.
Joe sold his shares for {}
Joe paid {} to his broker for selling his shares.
Joe made a total of {}
""".format(
    TotalPricePaid, CommissionPaid, TotalSellPrice,
    CommissionSellPaid, ProfitIfAny))
```

Comment: Haha, thanks! What a simple mistake to totally confuse me.